# Creating JSON type Column in SQLite with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, json, sqlite, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to create JSON type Column in SQLite with sqlalchemy?
I've tried

```
import sqlalchemy.types as types
...
myColumn = Column(types.JSON())
```

and

```
from sqlalchemy import JSON
...
mycolumn = Column(JSON)
```

Both get error message:

> Compiler  can't render element of type

Wondering if there is any solution in sqlalchemy or I should just change into SQL instead. Thanks in advance.

[Updates] SQLite version 3.16.0

Comment: what version of SQLite are you using?  It may not support the JSON type.

Comment: SQLite version 3.16.0 But how shouid I check if it supports JSON type or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JSON was not added to SQLite until version 3.9.  You'll either need to upgrade your SQLite or convert your json to a string and save it as such, while converting it back to a json object when you pull it out.

Answer (score 10):

My solution is:

```
import json
from sqlalchemy import TypeDecorator, types

class Json(TypeDecorator):

    @property
    def python_type(self):
        return object

    impl = types.String

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        return json.dumps(value)

    def process_literal_param(self, value, dialect):
        return value

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        try:
            return json.loads(value)
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            return None

...

myColumn = Column("name", Json)
```

For more information: [TypeDecorator](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html#sqlalchemy.types.TypeDecorator)

Answer (score 9):

SQLAlchemy [1.3](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/changelog/migration_13.html#change-3850) includes support for [SQLite JSON extension](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html), so don't forget to upgrade:

```
pip install --user -U SQLAlchemy
```

The dialect specific type [`sqlite.JSON`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/sqlite.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.JSON) implements JSON member access, usable through the base type [`types.JSON`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.JSON) as well.