# Retriving all rows of a table as list in sqlite db using sqlAlchemy

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy, python-3.6

I would like to retrieve all rows of a query as  a list. I am writing the following code :

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
from my_models import User

engine = create_engine('sqlite:////my_db.sqlite')
session_ = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
qr = session_.query(User)
qr.all()
```

But I get this error:

```
    json_deserializer = dialect._json_deserializer or json.loads
AttributeError: 'SQLiteDialect_pysqlite' object has no attribute '_json_deserializer'
```

_ Note that the same code is working fine when the data base is mysql ( creating the appropriate engine).

_ I am using python3.6

Comment: Yes. I can iterate over it, but the problem here it returns an error. So I can not even use it.

Comment: Do you happen to use `JSON` type in your `User` model? SQLite does not support it, while MySQL does – as does Postgresql, but in that case one should use the Postgresql dialect specific variant for better operator support.

Comment: Yes. I am using Json type. Myabe this what causes the problem and sqlite do not support it.

Comment: @IljaEverilä thank you. It is migration from mysql to sqlite.

Comment: It might be possible to create custom [compiler extensions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/compiler.html) that handle the JSON type to text conversion for SQLite, though I wonder if it's worth the trouble.

Comment: ah thank you for the link. I wonder if I should close this question or keep it for others who can have the same problem. Maybe you can change your comments to an answer.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html would probably be a major part of the equation.

Comment: Related, though not quite a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46712393/creating-json-type-column-in-sqlite-with-sqlalchemy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166538/discussion-between-ilja-everila-and-agstudy).

Comment: @IljaEverilä thanks a lot!!!!