# Is a sqlalchemy-sqlite database currently (01/2018) directly compatible with JSON objects?

Tags: python, json, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm currently trying to create a database that has a column for a JSON object:

```
import sqlalchemy as sql
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.types import JSON

# Creating the Base Object for the tables.
Base = declarative_base()

class Observations(Base):
    # Declaring the tablename.
    __tablename__='observations'

    # Defining the PK column.
    OBS_id=sql.Column(sql.Integer, primary_key=True)

    # Defining a FK column to stabilishes the connection between this table
    # and the ActiveRegion table.
    ar_id=sql.Column(sql.Integer, sql.ForeignKey(ActiveRegion.AR_id))

    # Creating a column to store the sharp metadata as a json object.
    hmi_meta_data = sql.Column('hmimetadata', JSON, nullable=False)
```

However when I run the code to build the database I get a `CompileError` that says:

```
CompileError: (in table 'observations', column 'hmimetadata'): Compiler <sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.base.SQLiteTypeCompiler object at 0x1c1e2b45f8> can't render element of type <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.JSON'>
```

I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46712393/creating-json-type-column-in-sqlite-with-sqlalchemy) already on SO some workarounds to implement a column with a JSON object but since this question was asked a while ago I was wondering if there is a native support that dismiss the needs of such implementations.

According to sqlalchemy types [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.JSON) JSON types should works on SQL backends that have an actual JSON type which includes SQLite as of version 3.9. I was checking my version which is 3.26 and it is the last release (sqlite release [website](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_26_0.html)). Is this then a milestone for a future sqlalchemy release then? Or is there something else I'm not considering?

Thanks.

Comment: SQLite JSON support will be introduced in SQLAlchemy version 1.3. Check that you have a recent enough version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed in the comment sqlalchemy is supporting JSON in version 1.3 which can be downloaded [here](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/download.html) and it's currently a beta version. The documentation for the new version is already [available](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/index.html) as well as the [changelog](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/changelog/migration_13.html) from version 1.2.